# How to programmaticaly create visual studio keyboard shortcut for VS operation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Hi VS 2015 is buggy and i had to restore some of my shortcuts from time to time. F.e. ctrl + ; for LineEnd and some others. Is there a way to do this programmaticaly, through the macros or so on?

Solved. There is updated script that not clear all keyboard shortcuts assigned to vs command (it helps avoid develor VSIX):

```
using System;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        string commandName = "Edit.LineEnd";
        string shortcut = "Text Editor::ctrl+;";

        EnvDTE.Command cmd= DTE.Commands.Item(commandName, 0);

        // Retrieve the current bindings for the command.
        Object[] bindings = ((System.Object[])(cmd.Bindings)); 
            // Get the number of bindings for the command.
            int bindingNumber = bindings.Length; 
            // Add two more elements to the array to accomodate two
            // new commands.
            // Create temp variable for copying values. 
            // Arrays are zero-based in C#.
            object[] temp = new object[bindingNumber + 1]; 
            System.Array.Copy( bindings, temp, Math.Min(bindings.Length, temp.Length)); 
        bindings = temp;

            // Add the new bindings to the existing ones in the array.
            bindings[bindingNumber] = shortcut; 

        cmd.Bindings = bindings;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your installation has a problem, you should repair it, not assume that VS is buggy and try to cover it up. The problem will remain and probably get worse. As for shortcuts, why not simply *reset* them? Or export/import them from "Tools > Import and Export Settings"? BTW LineEnd is just the End key.

Comment: Check [Identifying and Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx). It shows how to export settings, including keyboard shortcuts

Comment: You can run devenv.exe /ResetSettings to revert to the default settings across the entire IDE. If you don't mind losing any other customizations you have possibly put in place, that is.

Comment: Off cause i have ResetSettings reset shortcuts, saving and restoring vs settings and made a lot of voodo, runic and gypsy magic. VS 2015 is buggy and i find no magic to keep pair of my favorite key shortcuts safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        this.DTE = DTE;
        SetShortcut("Edit.LineEnd", "Text Editor::ctrl+;");
    }

    private void SetShortcut(string commandName, string shortcut)
    {
        EnvDTE.Command command = DTE.Commands.Item(commandName, 0);
        command.Bindings = shortcut;
    }

    EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE;
}
```

See [Command.Bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.command.bindings.aspx) documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Great tool, it solve my problem, perhaps with a little hardcore :) Warning this scritp remove all defined keyboard shortcuts from vs command.